# sas selecting what to output to sas log

Tags: debugging, sas, dataset

I have a huge program, is there sas code that I can use to show me the order of the outputs, so which one was created first, second, third...etc, without any additional information that is generated in the sas log. I'm trying to trace certain datasets and isolated them. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by order of the outputs?  Output datasets? Do you mean you have a bunch of datasets and want to know the order in which they were created? (Creation date of each file?). I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between your `DATA` steps, use the `%PUT` statement below:

```
options nosource nonotes;

data class;
    set sashelp.class;
run;

%PUT %trim(&syslast) created at %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime25.6).;

data air;
   set sashelp.air;
run;

%PUT %trim(&syslast) created at %sysfunc(datetime(),datetime25.6).;
```

This will only write to the log:

WORK.CLASS created at 15APR2016:08:46:59.555348.

WORK.AIR created at 15APR2016:08:46:59.568947.

Comment: `&SYSDATE` and `&SYSTIME` are constants, set at the start of the program. If you want to know the exact time and date of creation of the data, you need to use `%sysfunc(datetime(),datetime25.6)` or similar.